# How to pass intent extras to broadcast reciever?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I've been trying to get an android application to install an APK on the sdcard programmatically and to delete the apk once it's installed.

This is how I'm doing it:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType("ApkFilePath...","application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.putExtra("apkname", apkName);
activity.start(intent);

And I have written a braodcast-reciever class so that I can handle apk deletion process there once the app is installed. But I can't get extras passed from my intent in the broadcast-reciever.